# How to Retrieve a Taxonomy Term's ID?

Tags: taxonomy

I am trying to display a taxonomy term's image and need the term's ID. For some reason I am having trouble getting the ID. If I hard-code the ID in place of `$term_id` everything works as expected, but of course that doesn't help in a template.

For reference, my taxonomy is `Organizations` and each entry is the name of an organization.

This is the first time I've really gotten into WordPress functions and templates.

Here's what I have:

```
    <?php 

      $terms = get_field('listing_organization');
      $term_id = get_queried_object_id();

      if( $terms ): ?>

        <ul>

        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($term_id, thumbnail); ?>" />
          <h2><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></h2>
          <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ID is contained within the term object you are already using in your loop:

```
echo z_taxonomy_image_url( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this on an archive page?

Try to get the term ID with this instead:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

Comment: I'm not having luck with that.

It's not an archive page. I have it set up where a company's page displays the organizations that the company belongs to in addition to other company info.

Comment: in what template are you using this?

Comment: The template is custom to the theme I'm using (Listify). The template itself is called 'content-single-job_listing.php'

Comment: that's a taxonomy template?

Comment: that's a page template used by the theme.